# Changing homepage

Tags: 7

I have to change dynamically the homepage according to the server HTTP_HOST.
I've tried to update `$_GET['q']` inside the settings.php.
It works but, the internal drupal function `drupal_is_frontpage()` compares with the `drupal_get_variable('site_frontpage')`.
A suggestion ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try either the [domain access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) or [subdomain](http://drupal.org/project/subdomain) module.

**Update:**

As a poor-man's solution, in settings.php, you could try the following:

```
if ($server['HTTP_HOST'] == 'foo.com'){
  $conf['site_frontpage'] = 'node/XXX';
} elseif ($server['HTTP_HOST'] == 'bar.com') {
  $conf['site_frontpage'] = 'node/YYY';
}
```

Thanks @Chance G for a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the anwsers @greg_1_anderson and @Chance G. In fact, the variable `$conf` is not defined in settings.php. I've move this `switch` after bootstrap call, in index.php (I will move this in a module), but it works correctly. 

Finnaly, updating `$_GET['q']` and `$conf['site_frontpage']` solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: In fact, this code must be inserted after `menu_execute_active_handler()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings file or theme preprocess file you could add something like the following using the [variable_set](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) function:

```
if ($server['HTTP_HOST'] == 'foo.com'){
  variable_set('site_frontpage', 'node/XXX');
} elseif ($server['HTTP_HOST'] == 'bar.com') {
  variable_set('site_frontpage', 'node/YYY');
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but a bad implementation; variable_set will affect all visitors to the site. If you have multiple page requests all at the same time, some users will get the frontpage set for other users. Make the change to $conf['site_frontpage'] in settings.php and it should work right, though.

Answer (score 0):

`variable_set()` is a really really bad idea because it touches the Database everytime. Bad for performance, logically, etc... Simply don't do that ;)

But I extended the solution from @greg_1_anderson a bit by also ensuring the front page is not being delievery from cache, see my blog post: https://julian.pustkuchen.com/node/794

I think that's a good solution for Drupal 7. For Drupal 8 I didn't yet find a simple solution, perhaps someone has an idea.